# Sorting each row separately using custom list

Tags: excel, customization, sorting, vba

I have researched several sites for two days and have come up with a couple of macros that are close to what I need but not exact. If I'm not in the right place, will someone please direct me to where I need to go?

I'm hoping someone out there can tweak what I have so it will work. Below is a copy of the the Excel rows I'm working with.

MT  MD  BB  AA  CC
MT  MD  AK
MT  MD  LX  A2
MT  MD  LA  SO  VL  AH  PH

A7  LW  A1
SC
MT  MD  GL  A1
MT  MD
A7  A1  A2
MT  MD  A1  AH

MT  MD  A4  AD  A7  AK  A1  AH  PH  A2
A7  AH  AJ  PH

. I need each row to be sorted using a custom list:

**MT MD BU ED TI AS CI MP FF NF A1 A2 A7 LX GL CR BA WS**

Anything not on the list but appears on the spreadsheet would fall to the end of the list.
Below are two macros that are close but not quite. (I have made modifications to the originals)

```
Sub test()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("3:100").Sort _
    Key1:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("3:100").Row(2), _
    Header:=xlYes, _
    Orientation:=xlSortRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    SortMethod:=xlPinYin
End Sub     


Sub Macro5()

    Rows("3:30").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Rows("2:2"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "MT,BU,MD,ED,TI,AS,CI,MP,FF,NF,A1,A2,A7,LX,CR,BA,GL,WS", DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Rows("3:30")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to sort the rows individually, try:

```
Dim lRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For lRow = 3 To 30
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=.Parent.Rows(lRow & ":" & lRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "MT,BU,MD,ED,TI,AS,CI,MP,FF,NF,A1,A2,A7,LX,CR,BA,GL,WS", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange .Parent.Rows(lRow & ":" & lRow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next lRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```